# Weibull distribution cdf

Tags: jquery, distribution, weibull

I need to calculate weibull distribution using jquery. The formula used by me is mentioned below:

[image: Weibull cdf formula]

If my X process follows a Weibull distribution which has parameters alpha, beta, and gamma, what is the probability of getting an outcome less than or equal to a particular value x?" The values of alpha, beta, gamma, and x are all inputs to the function, and the output is a probability.

I need some clarification regards how to calculate those three parameters (alpha, beta  & gamma). Is there any specific formula to calculate those parameters? I've searched a lot but still didn't get any idea.

Is there any jquery plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the wording of your question, I get the impression that you don't actually understand [what a cumulative distribution function is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function).  In your case, it says "If my X process follows a Weibull distribution which has parameters alpha, beta, and gamma, what is the probability of getting an outcome less than or equal to a particular value x?"  The values of alpha, beta, gamma, and x are all inputs to the function, and the output is a probability.

If you have observations of a real-world process you are trying to model, you can try to estimate the parameters based on your data using a variety of [distribution fitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_fitting) techniques.